# SQL Server : converting time in hh:mm am/pm format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to display my results with a hh:mm am/pm format however my query below is only working for the am results but not time from 12:00pm and on

```
select 
    timein, timeout, 
    SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, timein, 108), 1, 5),  
    SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, TimeOut, 108), 1, 5)
from 
    timeinandoutTable 
where 
    progtype = 'cmp' 
    and TimeIn is not null and TimeOut is not null
```

Results

```
Timein                  TimeOut            timeinresult  timeoutresult 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1900-01-01 15:00:00     1900-01-01 16:10:00    15:00        16:10
1900-01-01 10:00:00     1900-01-01 17:00:00    10:00        17:00
1900-01-01 09:30:00     1900-01-01 16:00:00    09:30        16:00
```

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/ also please don't ever use variable-length types like `varchar` without specifying the length, see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Do this at the client, not at the server.

Answer (score 1):

You must use one of the styles that uses "AM/PM".  Your example (108) DOES NOT.  Use something like this instead (style 100, take the last 7 chars):

```
select timein, timeout, 
substring(convert(varchar(19), timein, 100), len(convert(varchar(19), timein, 100)) - 6, 7), 
substring(convert(varchar(19), timeout, 100), len(convert(varchar(19), timeout, 100)) - 6, 7)
from timeinandoutTable 
where progtype= 'cmp' and TimeIn is not null and TimeOut is not null
```

Here is a self-contained query you can run to see this working:

```
select convert(datetime, 'Dec 31 2015 10:25PM', 100) as datetime_value, 
substring(convert(varchar(19), 'Dec 31 2015 10:25PM', 100), len(convert(varchar(19), 'Dec 31 2015 10:25PM', 100)) - 6, 7) as my_string_value


datetime_value         | my_string_value
2015-12-31 22:25:00.000| 10:25PM
```